# Winterbash hats in Android app?

Tags: support, android-app, ios-app, winter-bash

I have some Winterbash hats. But they did not appear when I was using the Android app. Why is this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Winterbash is a temporary Javascript-driven add-on for the site. The mobile apps do not support such temporary extras, so you won't see the hats in the apps.

You *do* get some hats for using the mobile apps, however!

In 2014 I earned this very dashing beret-like thing; it was awarded for using the iOS app, for example:

[image: ninja with apple hat]

Other 2014 mobile specific hats were:

- [*On the road*](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/on-the-road) - Post a question using the mobile app.
- [*Bugdroid*](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/bugdroid) - Post, vote, edit or comment using the Android app.
- [*Not a cherry*](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/not-a-cherry) - Post, vote, edit or comment using the iOS app.
- [*Got a tablet for Christmas*](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/got-a-tablet-for-christmas) - Post on Christmas day using the mobile app. Presumably it doesn't *have* to be brand new. :-)

Comment: Martijn, in _Got a tablet for Christmas_ , the _post_ refers to question or answer, right?

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes, *post* means either an answer or a question. There is an implicit quality requirement; you'll need an upvote on the post.

Comment: Sadly the Winter Bash is nowhere to be seen in the mobile version of the website, either.

Comment: @hichris123: I don't see hats on mobile *this year*. The update you found concerns *last year*. Do you somehow see hats on iOS now?

Comment: It's apparently slightly broken, @MartijnPieters, but working for some: [Hat inconsistencies in iOS app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288531/hat-inconsistencies-in-ios-app).

Comment: @hichris123: must be my testflight build then (I'm in the testing program).